# Listing of assets?

Tags: android

I want to add files to assets directory and how many there are and what their paths are. How I list of files in my assets directory?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get a list of files in my assets directory?

Call `list()` on [an `AssetManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/AssetManager) to get a list of assets packaged in your app. You can get an `AssetManager` by [calling `getAssets()` on a `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context#getassets).

Note that these are not files on the device. They are files on your development machine; they are merely assets in the app.

> How can I form path strings or URLs to read each one individually?

That depends on what you mean by "read each one".

If you want to read the HTML in manually, call [`open()` on the `AssetManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/AssetManager#open), passing in the relative path to the asset.
IOW, for a file on your development machine in `app/src/main/assets/hi/there.html`, you would call `open("hi/there.html")`).

If you want to display the HTML in a `WebView`, use `file:///android_asset/hi/there.html` with `loadUrl()` on the `WebView`, for an asset located at the relative path `hi/there.html`.

Comment: Hi the problem here is that I want to do some analysis of the HTML that I am reading in, so I can't just load it into a webview right away.

Comment: Also, I want to read assets on the device, not on the developer machine. I don't have the emulator running at all anyway.

Comment: @nodnarbog: "the problem here is that I want to do some analysis of the HTML that I am reading in" -- then you would need to use the `open()` approach to get an `InputStream`. "I want to read assets on the device, not on the developer machine" -- your question refers to "files in my assets directory". Assets in an Android app are not files. You can use `AssetManager` to access your assets.

Comment: I seem to have finally loaded the HTML into a String, however when I try to use loadData to load it into a webview, I get a blank webview. Very odd. However when I try to load the webview with something simple like "<html>testing" that works fine.

Comment: @nodnarbog: You might need to configure your `WebView`, such as to allow JavaScript.

Comment: What if I'm unable to call getAssets, because I'm in a class that doesn't offer that, such as a model class?

Comment: @nodnarbog: A model class should not be doing I/O (files, assets, Web service, etc.). A repository should be doing the I/O, perhaps based on data from a model class.